# How to browse network camera in OSX ?

Tags: networking, camera, avfoundation, qtkit, imagekit

I'm writing a an Objective C software that will use  some network camera (IP based ). I've checked many api but i'm able to detect my TP-Link TL-SC3171 camera.
I'm using an Mac Book Pro.

Here are the api i've seen:

1-AV foundation: With AVCaptureDevice, the only device i can detect is Built-in iSight

2-QTkit: With  QTCaptureDevice, only  iSight cameras (external and built-in); USB and FireWire webcams can be detected.

3-With ImageKit and  ImageCapture, i'm supposed to be able to dynamically detects all cameras and scanners attached by USB or available over the network, but i can not see my TP-Link SC3171.

Do you know which api to i must use to browse any network camera ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the OS X image capture APIs purport to support network cameras -- they're all about locally connected devices.

Looking at that device's documentation, since you configure and preview it through a web interface, it seems more like a network streaming device. If you can get the URL to the MPEG-4 stream, maybe you could open that with an AVPlayer or QTMovie.

Basically, you're thinking about it the wrong way. From your app's point of view, it's not a camera, it's a server.